# How to have Google Authentication in expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am currently trying to create an app with Expo React Native. With different packages being deprecated, I have tried using `expo-auth-session`. Below is my code and the promptAsync calling is inside a button `onPress` event:

```js
    const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
        androidClientId: '',
        iosClientId: '',
        expoClientId: ''
    });

    promptAsync({ useProxy: false, showInRecents: true }) // Inside Button onPress()
```

The authentication menu pops up and I can login with my Google Account. However, it is returning

```
Something went wrong trying to finish signing in. Please close this screen to go back to the app.
```

In this situation I am not sure if I am being wrong of any steps. I am confident that there is no mistake to the `ClientId`.

Therefore, I am looking a replacement for the packages, or pointing out mistakes that I might have made either. Appreciate your time.